# JavaScript Math.round: Doesnt round object to 1 decimal

Tags: javascript, rounding

I have objects in array:

```
x[{a=2.99, b=5.11}{a=4.99, b=2.11}]
```

And I want it to display 1 decimal with Math round, as I use `Math.round(x[0].a*10)/10;` it displays 3, while it works fine if I use just numbers as `Math.round(2.99*10)/10`.

Why is that?

Comment: So how do you 'display' your values?

Comment: "Works fine" meaning what?

Comment: No, the question does **not** state the answer should be 2.9. Where does it state that? What is your understanding of the meaning of the word "round"?

Answer (score 0):

please try the below code

```
x[0].a.toString().match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/)[0]
```

you can round off to 1 by changing regex patter from `{0, 2}` to `{0, 1}`

Comment: No, don't use regexp to do number arithmetic or formatting.

Comment: since in this case we need to print the value, converting it to string and then applying regex to filter content seems fine but please let me know if there is any downside to it. I will be happy to correct my answer

Comment: Why do you think the problem reported by the OP exists?

Comment: This is a truncate, not a rounding

Comment: getting `3` is correct rounded value as 2.99 will round of to 3 so I believe truncating is correct option. If you want more than 2 characters, you can always do `x[0].a.toFixed(10).match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Thiss might work -- `Math.floor()` and `toFixed(1)`  are the keys here... rounding will cause the original input to change to the nearest integer.

```js
    function roundToTenth(inputVal) {
      return Math.floor(inputVal * 10) * 0.1;
    }
    
    console.log(roundToTenth(2.99).toFixed(1));
```

Division is slower than multiplication is generally - and definitely  using  Regular Expression Matching is going to be slower than multiplication  is....

All I'm doing in the code above is saying  "Take  the number  times 10 and then turn it into a straight Integer with no Decimals,

so
`2.99 * 10 =  29.9`    which then becomes   `29`

finally, since I use the operation `* 0.1`  it becomes a float like  `2.900000004`  and I use `toFixed(1)` to strip out all those pesky `0s` at the end

Comment: `parseInt` is designed to parse strings into integers, not do rounding. Anyway, your `roundToTenth` routine does not round, it truncates.

Comment: And we don't know that there might not be a string like "2.99" in the input at some point?

Comment: You're not running `parseInt` on the input. You're running it on a number which is the result of multiplying by ten. What is happening underneath is that `inputVal * 10` will be converted to string, and then run through `parseInt`.

Comment: Yes, I know.  If you don't use parseInt() then it doesn't come out with the correct answer in my code

Comment: What about `Math.floor()`?

Comment: a better alternative.